# GDAL DestroyFeature() method produces segmentation fault

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault, gdal

I have a method which loads `OGRFeature`'s and extracts data from them.
However, when I call the method `OGRFeature::DestroyFeature()` to release the memory, I get a segmentation fault.

```
void Class::processFeatures() {
    OGRFeature* feature;
    feature = layer->GetNextFeature();
    while( feature != NULL ) {
        handleGeometries(); //Handling Geometries
        doY(); //Handling Fields
        OGRFeature::DestroyFeature(feature);
        feature = layer->GetNextFeature();
    }
}

void Class::handleGeometries() {
    OGRGeometry* geometry = feature->GetGeometryRef();
    //Some handling code
    delete geometry;
}
```

The code runs and saves the information if I exclude the `DestroyFeature`. This example does work.

```
#include "gdal.h"
#include "gdal_priv.h"
#include <ogrsf_frmts.h>

int main()
{
    GDALAllRegister();
    GDALDataset* map;
    map = (GDALDataset*) GDALOpenEx("shape.shp",GDAL_OF_VECTOR,NULL,NULL,NULL);

    if (map)
    {
        OGRLayer* layer = map->GetLayer(0);

        OGRFeature* feature;
        feature = layer->GetNextFeature();
        while( feature != NULL ) {
            OGRFeature::DestroyFeature(feature);
            feature = layer->GetNextFeature();
        }

        GDALClose(map);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What is causing the problem? And how would I solve it?

EDIT: second example expanded

Comment: What are you doing with the feature inside the for-loop? Have you tried to test if the feature pointer is not null?

Comment: I have tested already tested the using a while loop and `GetNextFeature` however this problem still occurs. I added the feature to the inside when I started running out of ideas.

Comment: Is there some line in your code where you retrieve other resources from the layer and then destroy them, *before* this loop?

Comment: Nothing beforehand after loading into a  `GDALDataset`,  this is the first thing I do. After the included code, I close the `GDALDataset` and move on with the saved data.

Comment: I do not understand clearly what you mean with the "saved data"... Anyway, I suspect the problem lays in the release of the dataset itself. Try to run the program, removing the GDALDataset closing part, but leave the DestroyFeature() there. If it does not crash, then review your flow. If it crashes again, please provide the full code snippet, otherwise I can not help you further.

Comment: The seg fault still occurs, I have added all the related code up until to the map release

Comment: I've edited your post with a minimal reproducible example. As far as I can tell the code is fine. I tested it with some shape files I have and had no issues... the code will work if at least a layer is present. Have you tried opening your shape file with qgis?

Comment: The shapefiles work as intended if I remove the `DestroyFeature()`, and they also load in QGIS. I can't see any differences other than the pointer for the `GDALDataset` being passed to a class which handles the this however I'm not sure why this would effect it. I also wonder if GDALClose is handling the feature.

Comment: The feature you get with GetFeature() is "a feature now owned by the caller" as the GDAL doc states. So you should free it to avoid leaks. Anyway this behavior is usually due to a memory corruption or a misplaced free somewhere. Do you get a ref to the OGRSpatialReference of the dataset somewhere, and then free it? If you do so then DestroyFeature will complain because it tries to access the sp. Does it crash If you run the exact minimal code (with no setMin, doX, doY fuctions) that I added in your question?

Comment: The minimal case works. I think your help has lead me to find a possible cause to the problem. after opening the feature, duing `doX()` I open geometry and delete it using the `delete` command, but not the pointer I cast it to (dependent on geometry type handling). Would this cause the issue? Is there a special way to delete geometries I am unaware of?

Comment: Ok, do not delete the geometry you get from a feature, as they still belong to the feature itself and will be destroyed with it. Check the docs of GetGeometryRef, that is the api I think you are using. Use Steal geometry to get the ownership of the geometry, if you really need to.  Otherwise simple remove the delete instruction and check if it works.

Comment: This seems to have fixed it I will update the example so you can create a suitable answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer comes after a series of comments/edits to the original question that lead to this conclusion:

Deleting the geometry pointer in the handleGeoemtry() method is what causes the memory violation when the `DestroyFeature()` function is called, as the geometry `OGRFeature::GetGeometryRef()` returns a reference to an object but does not transfer the ownership to the caller.

You can use the `OGRFeature::StealGeoemtry` to take the ownership, or simply remove the `delete geometry` instruction as the `DestroyFeature()` function will dispose of it anyway.